# How to add one class at the time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prepend

I want to add new div with same design on the box when I click on it! But I could click and it appears new divs as I wished, but I want to add one at the time not more than one. I mean if I click once and one new div should appear and if I click again 1 new div should appear. But when i clicked many times it adds more than one! Why?

```
$(".answered_box").click(function () {
$(".answered_box").prepend('<div class="answered_box"> hej </div>');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbNEC/

Thanks for the the help!

Comment: is it like http://jsfiddle.net/jbNEC/1/ this you are looking for?

Comment: Yes he is. In your question, user, you adding new div to element with class `.answered_box`. On next click you do same, but there are 2 elements with such class. On next click you do same, but there are 4 elements with such class. Etc.

Comment: You're adding elements inside elements, but it sounds like what you really want is siblings, so you should be using before() not prepend(), and the issue resolves itself -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jbNEC/4/**

Comment: So, it means that I should have put click method on one div and not to every class?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="answered_box"> test </div>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$(".answered_box").live('click',function () {
    $('#container').append($(this).clone());
     });

});
```

Here is [**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VVQVF/)

Comment: what does clone() mean?

Comment: makes a copy of the element

Comment: but i am used to on(); but why have you used live() instead of on();?

Comment: You can use on instead of live, reason is I am used to live

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use this:-

```
$(this).prepend('<div class="answered_box"> hej </div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".answered_box").click(function () {
        // only apply on "this" and not on all members with the class.
        $(this).prepend('<div class="answered_box"> hej </div>');  
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is adding the div with class `answered_box` to all the divs with class `answered_box`. You should add the parent div and add divs to there.

Answer (score 0):

Use **this** keyword it means to **owner** only the current div(class) will executed and other div's with same are omited.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 

 $(".answered_box").click(function () {
$(this).append('<div class="answered_box"> hej </div>');
  });

 });
```